# parse data after useQuery before render

Tags: reactjs, graphql

Im trying to build a user page that displays a data tree. But the problem that I run across is finding the right way to query / parse / then render. I placed the parse into onComplete: because otherwise it couldn't read properties of data before query completed. But once I did that the render could not read User. so I declared it as a let.  Currently I have my data displaying in console but the "user undefined" condition is rendering.

```
const { userName: userParam } = useParams();

  const { loading, data } = useQuery(userParam ? QUERY_SINGLE_USER : QUERY_ME, {
    variables: { userName: userParam },
    onCompleted: parseData,
  });
 function parseData() {
    user = JSON.parse(data.me.jsonString);
    console.log(data.me.jsonString);
    return user;
  }
  let user;
if (loading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  if (user == undefined) {
    return <h4>You need to be logged in to see your profile page.</h4>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <div id="user-tree">
        {userParam ? <h1>{user.userName}'s Tree</h1> : <h1>My Tree</h1>}

        <OrgChartTree user={user} />

        <FriendsList user={user} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

so turns out i was way over complicating it i just needed to declare user and then conditionally run the parse like below

```
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(
    userParam ? QUERY_SINGLE_USER : QUERY_ME,
    {
      variables: { userName: userParam },
     
    }
  );
  let user;
if (loading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }
  if (error) {
    return <div> AHHHHHHHHHHHHHH.......</div>;
  }
 if (data) {
    user = JSON.parse(data.me.jsonString);
  } 
return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      {userParam ? <h1>{user.userName}'s Tree</h1> : <h1>My Tree</h1>}
      {user != undefined ? (
        <div id="user-tree">
          <OrgChartTree user={user} />

          <FriendsList user={user} />
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div>building graph...</div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) hook for `user` instead